# API authentication with python request

Tags: python, api, authentication, python-requests

I am testing some APIs whose only documentation is the response to the requests for the respective APIs. Basically when I execute I get for all the requests: `{"detail":"Authentication credentials were not provided."}` except for the login request which is successful, this is because I obviously pass the parameters to it as required I guess.

Below is my code for the requests:

```
import requests

credential = {'identity' : 'xxxxxxx', 'password': 'xxxxxx'}
#use the 'auth' parameter to send requests with HTTP Basic Auth: auth = ('xxxxxx', 'xxxxxxx')
    
#url list
api_login = 'https://xxxxxxxx/api/login'
api_channel = 'https://xxxxxxxx/api/channel'

#requests
r_login = requests.post(url=api_login, data = credential)
print(r_login.status_code)

r_channels = requests.get(url=api_channel)
print(r_channels.text)
```

If it can help, following the info for the API that fail the authentication:

```
Curl

curl -X 'GET' \
  'https://xxxxxxx/api/channels' \
  -H 'accept: application/json' \
  -H 'X-CSRFToken: xxxxxxxxx'

Request URL
https://xxxxxxx/api/channels
```

At the moment I've tried using basic authentication in the GET request and passing the headers in the documentation curl but as I'm not a bit practical I might have got it wrong.

Comment: Try to pass credentials in header instead of passing into body.

Comment: simple requests are stateless, so even if you manage to login, the next call will be unauthenticated. you should use the [session](https://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/#session-objects) object of requests or manually apply the tokens you get to every single request you make

Comment: @Nullman same error this way, but I might have got it wrong

`import requests

credential = {'identity' : 'xxxxxxx', 'password': 'xxxxxx'}
#use the 'auth' parameter to send requests with HTTP Basic Auth: auth = ('xxxxxx', 'xxxxxxx')

#session
s.request.Session()

#url list
api_login = 'https://xxxxxxxx/api/login'
api_channel = 'https://xxxxxxxx/api/channel'

#requests
s.post(url=api_login, data = credential)

r_channels = s.get(url=api_channel)
print(r_channels.text)`

Comment: @SmitParmar added in the get request after the `url  r_channels = requests.get(url=api_channel, headers={'identity': 'xxxx', 'password': 'xxxxx'})` and same for the token `r_channels = requests.get(url=api_channel, headers={'X-CSRFToken': 'xxxxxxxx'})`

Comment: can you check the result (not just the status code) of your login request? make sure you get the token and that the token is added to your headers! you may have to add the token manually to your SESSION headers

Comment: @Nullman with content,text and json it print only {}, with headers it get this: {'Date': 'Wed, 18 May 2022 10:22:00 GMT', 'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'Transfer-Encoding': 'chunked', 'Connection': 'keep-alive', 'allow': 'POST, OPTIONS', 'x-frame-options': 'DENY', 'vary': 'Cookie', 'x-content-type-options': 'nosniff', 'referrer-policy': 'same-origin', 'strict-transport-security': 'max-age=15724800; includeSubDomains', 'CF-Cache-Status': 'DYNAMIC'}.
In the curl doc it use a -H 'X-CSRFToken: xx', I tried adding it in the GET as indicated in the comment above but nothing.

Comment: if you're not getting the token then i think you fail logging in

Comment: @Nullman on the documentation in the response headers of the login request the keys are the same, only some values are different.